# Is there a valid difference between home-loan and mortgage tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Should both the [home-loan](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-loan) and the [mortgage](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortgage) tag exist?

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a good reason we need both.  Perhaps [home-loan](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-loan) should be a synonym for [mortgage](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortgage).

Answer (score 1):

Great idea, this is now complete!

Comment: You don't waste any time, eh?  I think we were trying to get some more community "me too" before moving on this.  Pardon my Canadian ;-)